# C# в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, численные-методы

Есть программа на C# которая реализует метод Жордана-Гаусса.
Помогите пожалуйста, перевести код с консоли в Windows Forms. Если можете, с объяснениями, пожалуйста!
Заранее спасибо!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ class Program
   {static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       double matrixa, matrixb, firstrowa, obernenyj, firtsrowb, secondrowa, secondrowb, lastrowa, lastrowb;
       //ввод матрицы
           Console.WriteLine("MatrixCount:4");
           int n=4;
           double[,] A = new double[,]{{2, 2, 1, 4},{3, 1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3, 1}};
           Console.WriteLine("  (2 2 1 | 4)");
           Console.WriteLine("A=(3 1 2 | 3)");
           Console.WriteLine("  (2 1 3 | 1)");
           //нахождение первого элемента  !=0
           // A[i, 0] - первый элемент строки
           // k- номер строки, где первый элемент !=0
           int k = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
           {for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
               {if (A[i, 0] != 0)
                   {   k = i;
                       break; }
                   else { Console.WriteLine("A[i, 0]=0!!!!!!!!");
                   break;
                   }  } }
           // замена строки с A[i,j]=0 на ненулевую
           int value;
           double a;
           Console.WriteLine("__________zamina______");
           for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
           { for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
               {if (A[i, 0] == 0)
                   {value = i;a = A[i, j];
                       A[i, j] = A[i + 1, j];
                       A[i + 1, j] = a;
                       Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]={2}", i, j, A[i, j]);
                   } } }
            //
           Console.WriteLine("Mass B");
           Console.WriteLine("Первую строку делим на первый элемент этой строки");
           
       double perelem=A[0, 0];
      
       
           double[,] B = new double[n-1,n];
           for (int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++)
           {for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
           {firstrowa = A[0, j];
           firtsrowb = B[0, j];
              
               if (i == 0)
               {
                   matrixb = firstrowa / perelem;
               B[i, j] = matrixb;
               }
             if (i == 1 )
             {
                 obernenyj = firtsrowb * A[i, 0];
                 B[i, j] = A[i, j] - obernenyj;
             }
             if (i == 2)
             {
                 obernenyj = firtsrowb * A[i, 0];
                 B[i, j] = A[i, j] - obernenyj;
             }
               Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]={2}", i, j, B[i, j]);  }   }
          
           double elem = B[1, 1];
           Console.WriteLine("__");
           for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
               {
                   secondrowa = A[1, j];
                   secondrowb = B[1, j];
                   A[i, j] = B[i, j];
                   if (i == 1)
                   {
                       matrixa = secondrowb / elem;
                       A[i, j] = matrixa;
                       
                   }
                   if (i == 2)
                   {
                       obernenyj = secondrowa * B[i, 1];
                       A[i, j] = B[i, j] - obernenyj;
                       
                   }
                  
                   Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]={2}", i, j, A[i, j]);  }  }
            Console.WriteLine("Результат:");
            
       for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        lastrowa = A[i, j];
                        B[i, j] = (lastrowa / A[2, 2]);
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        obernenyj = A[i + 1, j] * A[i, 2];
                        B[i, j] = A[i, j] - obernenyj;
                    }
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        obernenyj = A[i + 1, j] * A[i, 1];
                        B[i, j] = A[i, j] - obernenyj;
                    }

                    
                }
            }
       Console.WriteLine("x1={0}; x2={1}; x3={2}", B[0, 3], B[1, 3], B[2, 3]);
       Console.WriteLine("Ответ :({0};{1};{2}).", B[0, 3], B[1, 3], B[2, 3]);
       // выход
               Console.WriteLine("To exit press any key.");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы перевести код с консольного на Windows Forms, вам потребуется поменять `Console.WriteLine` допустим на `MessageBox.Show`или создать несколько `Label`. Другие же вычисления можно запихнуть в функцию при нажатии на одну или несколько кнопок в форме.